# Use Javascript frameworks without build tools like grunt and gulp?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp, javascript-framework

I'm trying out some modern Javascript frameworks like Angular, React, Vue and Ember, and they all want me to use build tools like `npm`, `grunt`, `gulp`, `maven`, etc.

Web-programming used to be fun. Just change some files, refresh the browser and see if it works. Now every time I change something, I have to build it again, which takes quite some time. I really hate to see that web-programming has become like this. I know the building can even be done automatically with these tools watching for file-changes, etc., but still, it just sucks.

My question is, when I want to use one of the mentioned frameworks, am I supposed to use the build-tools every time I want to run, or do I just need these for deployment and testing purposes (or not at all) ?

Comment: you know you don't have to use those bulid tools? y'know the purpose of them?

Comment: Well, they do things like minify JS, copy resources, compile SASS, concatenate mulptiple files into one...I understand all that, but these things are only needed when deploying I think, not during development. But all examples I tried seem to require using some build tool first before running it.

Comment: some of them have are mostly for locally (like compile sass, unless you're a super genius i'm sure you want to test your compiled css). most of them are to install dependencies like NPM. that being said i don't use a build tool for angular.js itself just for things surronding it like SASS or dependencies

Comment: If you want maintainable code, you should use these tools.

Comment: If you're interested in some performance metrics, you might want to check out: https://x-team.com/blog/rollup-webpack-parcel-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use these tools. They're mostly aimed at people who want to use frameworks in larger projects, and have features that let you compile hundreds of JS components into one file.  I personally use them mostly for automating build tests, unit tests, and bundling all the assets together on release days. Let's address the frameworks you mentioned one at a time:

**React**: React provides an already compiled version of their code on their getting started page
**AngularJS**: Same as react, there's just a file you can include, just look up "angular cdn"
**Vue**: They also have a file that you can just include.
**Ember**: See above

For most frameworks, you can just look up "*name of framework* CDN" to get an online hosted js file that you can quickly throw in to your projects for web development the old way.

Comment: I know they supply minified versions, but since every example seems to depend on running these command line tools, it's maybe not a good idea to ignore the fact that web-development has changed, wheter I like it or not... so I'm wondering if I should get used to these tools, or ignore them for now....

Comment: @Dylan If you're looking for a job in the front-end development world, there's a very good chance that your team will be using these tools, so you'll want to get used to them.  If you're just doing it on the side for fun, feel free to ignore them, or just try them out and see if you like them.

Comment: Well, that sucks then :)  I really don't like these tools (actually I hate anything that uses command line), but programming is my day job...

Comment: I personally use a gulp/webpack server, (gulp for build automation and webpack for testing), and after you run `gulp test`, you don't have to touch the command line again.  It auto-reloads your dev server when you save.

Comment: I also hate the command line and the bloat of tools in "modern" frontend dev. GUI interfaces became universally accepted for a reason - they are more efficient and user-friendly. Not everyone wants to return to the days of DOS.

Answer (score 1):

Some libraries require building the code, some don't. From the list that you had, none of them require it technically. They can all work by simply including the js file in a `<script>` tag. However, there are many frameworks/libraries (such as sass or coffeescript) which do require a build tool, because the source code must be compiled to become html/javascript/css as understood by the browser.

Also, there's not really any reason to be so against using build tools. As you said, they can run automatically on file change, so they're really just in the background.

Comment: Yes, but I'm on Windows, and running such a tool that watches for file changes is a bit 'ugly', in my opinion (for example, it uses a command-prompt window). I have multiple projects that I work on simultaneously, so this gets kind of messy, having all these watch processes running somewhere.

Comment: well maybe your issue isn't about whether you need build tools or not...maybe it's about whether you need a better operating system ;)

Comment: I just happen to like Windows and I hate command line (it's not 1976 anymore!).

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the command line. Don't hate on it just because it feels outdated or non-slick compared to a GUI. It's much more powerful. After using linux for a few months I noticed that I was doing even the most basic things, such as renaming files, from the command line. It's just so much easier, more powerful, and more convenient to type out a short line of text than to use a GUI to do it. I also used to think it was bad just because it's old. But the very reason it's been around so long is because it's still useful.